# How to fill a social media icon with color only inside using css

Tags: html, css

I have a Twitter svg icon without background:

```
<img id = "twitter_icon" src = "pictures/twitter.svg" alt = "Nema">

#twitter_icon {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

When I add background-color to it, the color fills the very icon and also square space around it. Is there any way to fill the very icon, so that the color does not go out of the icons border?

Will be thankful for any answer.

Comment: make your question and code cleaner , but i think you should do it with photoshop

Answer (score 0):

You should change your color in `svg` file, it has `<style>` rule.

```
<style>
.cls-1 {
    fill: #cb1717;
}
</style>
```

You can change it in Photoshop as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [font awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery) because it's easier to customize color. And after adding the fontawesome CDN, replace your code:

```
<img id = "twitter_icon" src = "pictures/twitter.svg" alt = "Nema">
```

With this code:

```
<span style="color: aqua"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></span>
```

Here is the link to add into your `<head> </head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<img>` tag is used to embed(add) an image in an HTML page.

Images are not technically inserted into a web page; images are linked to web pages. The `<img>` tag creates a holding space for the referenced image. What this means is the image that is linked by this tag is technically not a part of your `HTML` code.

**So what is happening** is the `background-color` that you are setting is adding color to a `div` that contains your image and since your image is transparent(which I am guessing is the case) it reflects the background color on which it is on.

**So what can you do**
Edit the image color in an image editing program like `photoshop` or in case you just downloaded this icon image then try looking for a colored version that matches the color that you want.